# how to add the html data highchart for send an email

Tags: javascript, c#, highcharts

I want to send html by email, the html display well in the email, but the charts (highcharts) don't display with the css:
it's look as:

PassFailBlockedNo RunUnder DebugPass Rate %11.8.50.339911.8.50.339411.8.50.3393v211.8.50.338711.8.50.338211.8.50.837311.8.50.836811.8.50.836011.8.50.835411.8.50.835111.8.50.8344v211.8.50.83380300150450600010025507511.8.50.8354● Pass: 474● Fail: 0● Blocked: 0● No Run: 0● Under Debug: 0● Pass Rate %: 100 
...

it is JS code:

```
function Send_Mail() {
    var html = "";
    html += "<html><head><style>";
    $.get("Highstock-5.0.14/code/css/highcharts.css").done(function(result) {
        html += result;
        $.get("Content/ReportStyle.css").done(function(result) {
            html += result + "</style></head>";
            $(".ToMail").each(function() {
                html += $(this).html();
            });
            html += "</html>";
            return $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ExecutionReportService.asmx/send_mail",
                data: JSON.stringify({ body: html }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json"
            });
        });
    });
}
```

C# code:

```
[WebMethod]
public void send_mail(string body)
{
    var smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.xxx.com");
    var mailMsg = new MailMessage
    {
        IsBodyHtml = true,
        From = new MailAddress("xxxx@gmail.com"),
        Subject = "Email subject",
        Body = body
    };


    mailMsg.To.Add("xxxx@gmail.com");
    smtp.Send(mailMsg);
}
```

Comment: I'm just curious, why you don't want to just take a screenshot of your chart with html2canvas, and then send this image in email?